# By mistake I undo the very first commit in my repo

Tags: git

I accidentally returned to the very first commit.

I used:

```
$ git update-ref -d HEAD
$ git rm --cached -r .
```

I didn't commit and push yet. How can i turn just my last commit.

Comment: Check the reflog?

Comment: Whatever article you used that arrived at that point, stop reading it. This is akin to "I accidentally bought a shotgun, loaded it with lethal ammo, pointed it at my leg and pulled the trigger, why did I lose my leg?" You shouldn't be using update-ref, at all, unless you know **precisely** what it will do. In other words, there should be so many warning signs you have passed along the way that I would be very hesitant calling this a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a remote for this repo and it's up-to-date, you can do:

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch name>
```

---

If that won't work, you can try to get at the lost commit hashes with:

```
git log --reflog
```

When I duplicated your steps on a test repo, the first commit in the log was what my branch used to point at. I repaired the branch with:

```
git reset --hard <commit hash from log>
```